# How are static objects shared across DLL and Windows Binary memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dll

I've got a bit of a design problem regarding DLL's, I'm currently in as you may call it and as wikipedia refers to it [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) The problem is as follows:

I've created a system which has multiple modules implemented as DLL's. These are used in an application and the DLL's can be loaded but not all of them are needed. If only things like mathematics is done it can link to 'Utilities.dll' and use this. 
The problem is, I've got a logger/tracer. This logs everything to a file and a debug console for me, the debug console is just a stream output. The issue is how to deal with multiple DLL's trying to work with the same log class. Seeing as the log class is in this 'Utilities.dll' and things like 'DataManagers.dll' and other dll's want to use the log class functionality as well. This includes loging to a file. I'm currently using critical sections to make sure no write clashing occurs but seeing critical sections are implemented in usermode I'd have to switch to mutexes or alike at some point to have kernel mode objects. But this having multiple instances of the log class across DLL memory would mean I would have some serious problems if I would just use a critical section.

What I can't seem to puzzle together is a way for all the DLL's to be able to use the same log class instance without having to link to the Utilities.dll one by one. I don't want to load 8 dll's into my demo project and have all those 8 refer to that one dll with the log class, this would be a bit of a chain reaction if I would need more things like the log class. Is there a way to properly do this ? Use the functionality of a class, with static functions inside a DLL in other DLL's and in a .exe windows binary using the same 'static' functions thereby not clashing in writing to a logfile or even the output stream for the debug console.

And if I'm completely wrong and trying to do the impossible please tell me and help to achieve something as close to this as possible. I know somewhat of a similair problem occurs when using the Singleton pattern in DLL's but this is solved by

What I've tried so far:

- When initializing the DLL's classes give them an instance of the log library but this defeats the purpose of the class having all static members.

I've also found this question which is similair ( even the name of the library my global tools are in how about that.. ) but it has not answered my question and has a bit of a different approach as well as being from '09. [How to mimic the "multiple instances of global variables within the application" behaviour of a static library but using a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076644/how-to-mimic-the-multiple-instances-of-global-variables-within-the-application)

Comment: Dll dll dll dll. What could be the problem? ;)

Comment: Yeah one DLL is easily doable, the problem is when more of them join the party, *sigh*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't "DLL Hell" at all.

It's a matter of basic understanding how DLLs work. A DLL is loaded at most once per process. So, if your DLL is used by multiple other DLLs, it still will exist once per process. If your log class object is implemented as a singleton in your DLL (e.g. a global object), then you have one object per process.

That one object should then be protected against concurrent use within the process. Critical Sections, being process-local, are a perfect match for that. You don't need a mutex, as two processes would each have their own copy of Utilities.DLL and its objects.

You *might* have an issue if your logger logs to a single fixed file. In that case, two processes would attempt to log to the same file. That's a design issue that you don't want to hack around anyway. Keep your log outputs separate, so make sure each logger writes to a unique log file.

Comment: And why the MSND couldn't explain this in the few lines you did I don't know. Thanks a lot, I didn't really know how the memory was organized when using multiple DLL's. But with what you said it means I don't really have an issue here. I can just use the utilities DLL and the singleton logging class in every module I create. 

And logging to the same file from different processes won't happen, it will be multiple threads logging to the same file but this is where the critical section helps me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As one can see from the image below, [image],

it is actually very common (against a very popular opinion) to have one DLL mapped several times in a process! It's a matter of basic understanding how DLLs work :-)

On a clean Windows XP system, you can see several instances of dxtmsft.dll, ieframe.dll, iepeers.dll, etc..within the iexplore.exe process. All these Dlls are just mapped at differents Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Use WinApi's CreatePipe or CreateNamedPipe function which is a queue-like communication section using windows' shared memory:

```
    BOOL WINAPI CreatePipe(
  __out         PHANDLE hReadPipe,
  __out         PHANDLE hWritePipe,
  __in          LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes,
  __in          DWORD nSize
);
```

or

```
    HANDLE WINAPI CreateNamedPipe(
  __in          LPCTSTR lpName,
  __in          DWORD dwOpenMode,
  __in          DWORD dwPipeMode,
  __in          DWORD nMaxInstances,
  __in          DWORD nOutBufferSize,
  __in          DWORD nInBufferSize,
  __in          DWORD nDefaultTimeOut,
  __in          LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes
);
```

Use ReadFile and WriteFile to communicate through the pipe from within other threads/processes.

To read from the pipe, a process uses the read handle in a call to the ReadFile function. ReadFile returns when one of the following is true: a write operation completes on the write end of the pipe, the number of bytes requested has been read, or an error occurs.

When a process uses WriteFile to write to an anonymous pipe, the write operation is not completed until all bytes are written. If the pipe buffer is full before all bytes are written, WriteFile does not return until another process or thread uses ReadFile to make more buffer space available.

Use one thread to handle the input and write the logs to file and/or console.

More on pipes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How would a pipe solve his problem?  A pipe is pretty much just a file, and it would require another process or at least another thread.  And just quoting Microsoft documentation isn't really an answer, especially when you don't make it clear you're quoting.

Comment: A pipe is not a file! It is (as I already stated) a shareable memory section across processes. It would solve the problem in such way that the pipe can be accessed as if it were a virtual ram-disk, where processes/threads can write or read from. You don't explicitly need another process to access a pipe, but I would recommend a worker thread that takes care of the pipe transactions (reads/writes). As far as I read, he needs some kind of file/console server instead of using thousands of instances of the same class.

Comment: Well the problem was more with how loading multiple DLL's in one process would affect the memory objects like singletons or static classes. I've implemented the WinAPI pipes before but I prefer just using fstream for this and block multiple threads using a critical section ( or a mutex if its shared across processes ).

Comment: @DragosDutu: A pipe does not behave like shared memory.  It behaves like a file.  After all, you access it with ReadFile and WriteFile.  How much more of a file do you need?

Comment: @CareyGregory WinApi uses ReadFile/WriteFile for almost any type of communications that require data transfer. Even tcp/ip sockets can be treated as handles to file. Aso USB communications and even the old school RS-232 data transfers (i.e. COM1/COM2?) can be handled over ReadFile/WriteFile. Check this out, especially the description of hFile parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DragosDutu: I'm aware of the nature of handles.  The fact remains that pipes behave like files, not shared memory.