# Where exactly do dll's get loaded?

Tags: windows, dll

I'm sure this question has been asked multiple times, and I have read tons of articles, but I still don
t understand it. Where exactly does a DLL get loaded? I am talking about the actual code of the DLL. When I call, lets say, MessageBoxA, where does it jump to? Does the code get loaded into my own process, or does it jump somewhere else(not even sure if this is possible)?

Please enlighten me, this has been bothering me for quite some time, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Just a quick thought: DLLs are loaded into the process memory space. So if there's 5 programs that use the same DLL, that lib will take up 5 places in memory; this is unlike code that is shared through interrupt handlers or COM objects, which reside in their own single memory space regardless of how many running programs need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLLs are loaded once per process. Here are some more details:

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Features_of_DLL):

> DLLs execute in the memory space of the calling process and with the same access permissions

As described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697484/241754):

> A DLL is loaded at most once per process. So, if your DLL is used by multiple other DLLs, it still will exist once per process.

[MSDN has plenty more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The system maintains a per-process reference count for each DLL. When a thread loads the DLL, the reference count is incremented by one. When the process terminates, or when the reference count becomes zero (run-time dynamic linking only), the DLL is unloaded from the virtual address space of the process.
> Like any other function, an exported DLL function runs in the context of the thread that calls it. Therefore, the following conditions apply:
>
> - The threads of the process that called the DLL can use handles opened by a DLL function. Similarly, handles opened by any thread of the calling process can be used in the DLL function.
> - The DLL uses the stack of the calling thread and the virtual address space of the calling process.
> - The DLL allocates memory from the virtual address space of the calling process.

[On Variable Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Variables that are declared as global in a DLL source code file are treated as global variables by the compiler and linker, but each process that loads a given DLL gets its own copy of that DLL's global variables. The scope of static variables is limited to the block in which the static variables are declared. As a result, each process has its own instance of the DLL global and static variables by default.

Before DLLs are loaded, they have to be found. There are specific rules about how Windows searches for DLLs, such as those listed at [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).